# stuck on Apache Cordova device is ready

Tags: cordova

i am using phonegap 2.9.0 with eclipse, trying to run the first example app on nexus 5 and it just stays on Apache Cordova: device is ready with green light flashing. i have no clue whats happening here! can someone help me out.

this is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-   scale=1,     minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  package="com.tenzin.tenzin" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1"      android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:allowBackup="true" >


    <activity android:name="tenzin" android:label="@string/app_name"


            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

two .html file in assets folder index.html and spec.html. Is that okaii ?

Comment: The green light flashing means it works. That is all the default app does. From here, you delete all that and start building your own app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove a few of line of codes. Try this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-   scale=1,     minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="spec.html">Go To Spec</a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, when doing that, after running the app in my phone it show the link "Go to spec".